# Setting a variable with if/else

Tags: ruby

I know that I can do something like this for a variable that switches between two states:

```
num = 0
...
if num == 0
    num = 1
else
    num = 0
end
```

but is there a way that I can do it more nicely, perhaps something like this:

```
num = 1 if num == 0 else 0
```

I know that that's not right but just something like that?

(coming from a python background here)

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're getting downvotes because your question doesn't show any research or effort. This is covered many times on Stack Overflow and on the internet. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
num = num == 0 ? 1 : 0
```

That evaluates to:

```
conditional ? return_this_if_true : return_this_if_false
```

Comment: I'm familiar with these, must've slipped my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can either use a ternary operator:

```
num = num == 0 ? 1 : 0
```

Or, you can use a plain old if/else, which returns the value of the evaluated block:

```
num = if num == 0
        1
      else
        0
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

I should add, if you're really talking about a toggle between 0 and 1 specifically, and not any two arbitrary states, you can just use `num ^= 1`, which is syntactic sugar for `num = num ^ 1`, where `^` is a binary xor operator.

For switching between true and false you can of course use `val = !val`.

Otherwise, yes, the ternary operator is the most concise form available.

Answer (score 1):

```
num = 1 - num
```

is another way...

Answer (score 1):

After first setting an array `arr` you could use `arr.rotate!.first`

```
arr = [0,1]
arr.rotate!.first  #=> 1
arr                #=> [1,0]
arr.rotate!.first  #=> 0
arr                #=> [0,1]
```

Alternaively use `cycle`

```
arr = [0,1].cycle
arr.next #=> 0
arr.next #=> 1
```

Or maybe make use of an enumerator (although this may be considered a bit overkill):

```
def alternator
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    arr = [0,1]
    loop do    
      y << arr.rotate!.first
    end    
  end
end

alt = alternator
alt.next #=> 1
alt.next #=> 0
```